# InfluxDB: Only two of my measurement entries end up to the database

Tags: python, influxdb

I have the following code:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
     measurements = [
       {
            "name": "name_of_my_measurement",
            "tags": {
                "customer_code": "FOO"
            },
            "fields": {
                "data_path": "s3://foo/2022-05-22",
                "count": "40690526"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "name_of_my_measurement",
            "tags": {
                "customer_code": "FOO"
            },
            "fields": {
                "data_path": "s3://foo/2022-05-21",
                "count": "10"
            }
        },
        ....
    ]

    for m in measurements:
        serialized_measurement = json_metric_serializer_format_to_influxdb_info(m)
        influxdb_utils.write_value_into_influxDB(client=i_client,
                                         tags=serialized_measurement.tags,
                                         fields=serialized_measurement.fields,
                                         measurement=serialized_measurement.measurement,
                                         time=serialized_measurement.time)




def json_metric_serializer_format_to_influxdb_info(meas):
    import collections
    influxdb_info = collections.namedtuple("influxdb_info", ["measurement", "fields", "tags", "time"])

    measurement = str(meas["name"])
    time = meas["fields"].get("time", "")
    fields = {x: meas["fields"][x] for x in meas["fields"] if not x == "time"}
    tags = meas["tags"]

    return influxdb_info(measurement=measurement, fields=fields, tags=tags, time=time)


def write_value_into_influxDB(client, tags, fields, measurement, time):
    import datetime

    if time == '':
        time = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')

    json_body = [
        {
            "measurement": "{measurement}".format(measurement=measurement),
            "tags": tags,
            "fields": fields,
            "time": time
        }
    ]

    client.write_points(json_body)
```

There might be 100 entries in the `measurements` array but when the code runs only TWO of all these entries end up in the `name_of_my_measurement` measurement table. These entries look completely random. For example these `data_path` field has a date, and there are 20 consecutive date paths in the measurements array and whenever I run the script and I check the measurement in Influx, another set of two of these measurements are written to the database. This looks completely random to me.

What can it be going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

This was a composite key problem. When I changed the measurements like this:

```
{
            "name": "name_of_my_measurement",
            "tags": {
                "customer_code": "FOO",
                "data_path": "s3://foo/2022-05-21"
            },
            "fields": {
                "count": "10"
            }
}
```

all the entries were successfully persisted.

[This also explains how you should choose your tags and fields more wisely than I did](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.2/write-data/best-practices/duplicate-points/#preserve-duplicate-points).